# Copy code with full package names

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Sometimes I want to copy a random block of my code that uses 3rd party libraries and share it with others.  e.g., Put it on a blog or something.  If I paste what I copy, a lot of context is lost because you can't see the packages of the 3rd party libraries.

The solution I use is to reduce this code into a small class and then share the whole class, import statements and all.  This is a lot of manual work, especially if it's just for a simple email to someone.  Is there a way I can copy a snippet of code and have it include the full package paths?

Comment: I have found that Eclipse creates the required imports if I copy-paste a method into a new, empty class.

Comment: @laune and intellij seems to know how to do that too, if I paste into a project with the required dependencies.  But, it's still a little more effort than I'd prefer to expend.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can use Scratch File (Ctrl-Alt-Shift-Insert) and copy-paste to it so imports should be copied too. It's a bit faster than copy-paste to new file.

Comment: It's new feauture, see it [here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/09/intellij-idea-14-eap-138-2210-brings-scratch-files-and-better-mercurial-integration/)